# Best way to transfer MySQL databases to Mac?

Tags: linux, macos, ubuntu, mamp, lamp

This post contains two questions. I recently got a Macbook Pro for college, and to continue my web development on (I come from an Ubuntu background). Right now, I'm using MAMP (mamp.info) as my AMP package for Mac, although I haven't really started using it yet. More or less just setting up my workspace right now. So, my questions are:

1. Do you think MAMP is the best choice for web dev on Mac? If not, what else would you recommend?
2. I was previously running LAMP on Ubuntu and have quite a few databases with tables in MySQL on there. How can I port these over to my Mac without recreating every individual database by hand? I tried a transfer of just the raw data files but, although they ported the databases, for some reason there were no tables in any of the databases. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Download a virtual machine, and install Linux and the rest of your server stack. More realistic development environment, and if you screw it up, you don't screw up your whole os. As for moving your databases, do a MySQL dump and then port run the SQL on your new server. Best way to do this is through PHPMyAdmin.

Answer (score 0):

If you are coming from an ubuntu environment then I will recommend MacPorts as that allows you to set up a packaging system similar to apt-get stuff in Ubuntu. Also if you screw up, you will not mess up any setting as it is contained. You can then install phpmyadmin and importing your database.

Please see the following URL to set up a LAMP stack on your MAC.

http://muddledramblings.com/rumblings-from-the-secret-labs/lamp-server-from-scratch-with-macports/